# How to customize rhandsontable headers in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rhandsontable

I want to customize a `rhandsontable` header starting from this `data.frame`:

```
DF <-
  data.frame(
    Qty1 = rnorm(72, mean = 40, sd = 10),
    Price1 = rnorm(72, mean = 30, sd = 10),
    Qty2 = rnorm(72, mean = 40, sd = 10),
    Price2 = rnorm(72, mean = 30, sd = 10),
    Zone = rep(c("NORTH", "SOUTH", "WEST"), each = 24)
  )
```

**This is what I was able to achieve so far**:

```
library(rhandsontable)
rhandsontable(DF, width = 600, height = 300) %>%
  hot_col(c("Price1", "Price2"), format = "$0,0.00")
```

[image]

**While this is what I'm trying to achieve**:

[image]

Within `R`, how do I:

- Customize the header to achieve the result in the picture above?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe nested headers are available for `rhandsontable` package in R: see [closed github issue](https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/204).

Comment: @Ben That was my suspicion as well. Thank you for posting it. I'll keep the question open in case it will be implemented one day.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to hide the headers. Instead I added an extra row at the top of my data frame with the header values. For this row you can then use merged columns in rhandsontable. You can then also disable edits for this row.

Comment: This seems a valid answer. However it could, and in my opinion should be improved with some code on how to actually do this.

Comment: Could you show us what you mean by this using the code OP provided?